# How can I get the selected array index onChange in the Listbox Headless UI component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, listbox, headless-ui

Below is the boilerplate code for Headless UI's ListBox. I need to access the selected array index from the parent component. The Listbox value is just the selected object. I have tried using event listeners in the Listbox.Option component to listen for keydown events (space and enter) and click events and the only one that works is the onClick event. Adding the KeyDown in Listbox.Option does not trigger the event.

```js
export default function Example() {
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState(people[0])

  return (
    <div className="fixed top-16 w-72">
      <Listbox value={selected} onChange={setSelected}>
        <div className="relative mt-1">
          <Listbox.Button className="relative w-full cursor-default rounded-lg bg-white py-2 pl-3 pr-10 text-left shadow-md focus:outline-none focus-visible:border-indigo-500 focus-visible:ring-2 focus-visible:ring-white focus-visible:ring-opacity-75 focus-visible:ring-offset-2 focus-visible:ring-offset-orange-300 sm:text-sm">
            <span className="block truncate">{selected.name}</span>
            <span className="pointer-events-none absolute inset-y-0 right-0 flex items-center pr-2">
              <ChevronUpDownIcon
                className="h-5 w-5 text-gray-400"
                aria-hidden="true"
              />
            </span>
          </Listbox.Button>
          <Transition
            as={Fragment}
            leave="transition ease-in duration-100"
            leaveFrom="opacity-100"
            leaveTo="opacity-0"
          >
            <Listbox.Options className="absolute mt-1 max-h-60 w-full overflow-auto rounded-md bg-white py-1 text-base shadow-lg ring-1 ring-black ring-opacity-5 focus:outline-none sm:text-sm">
              {people.map((person, personIdx) => (
                <Listbox.Option
                  key={personIdx}
                  className={({ active }) =>
                    `relative cursor-default select-none py-2 pl-10 pr-4 ${
                      active ? 'bg-amber-100 text-amber-900' : 'text-gray-900'
                    }`
                  }
                  value={person}
                >
                  {({ selected }) => (
                    <>
                      <span
                        className={`block truncate ${
                          selected ? 'font-medium' : 'font-normal'
                        }`}
                      >
                        {person.name}
                      </span>
                      {selected ? (
                        <span className="absolute inset-y-0 left-0 flex items-center pl-3 text-amber-600">
                          <CheckIcon className="h-5 w-5" aria-hidden="true" />
                        </span>
                      ) : null}
                    </>
                  )}
                </Listbox.Option>
              ))}
            </Listbox.Options>
          </Transition>
        </div>
      </Listbox>
    </div>
  )
}
```